# Vim Nerd-tree tab navigation is too slow

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

is there any way to jump between Nerd-tree tabs using numbers, example control-3 jump to third tab, or any way other than moving one by one ?

Comment: `:help tabpage.txt`

Comment: it is not the answer to your question, but once you are familiar with vim i suggest reading this: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/ and look into vinegar.vim

Answer (score 0):

Add this toggle to your .vimrc
**< leader > t** will toggle Nerd tree and it will also mirror the same tree if one is already open on another tab, otherwise it will just open a new one

`map <silent> <leader>t :NERDTreeToggle<CR> :NERDTreeMirror<CR>`